Cannot use GetFromJsonAsync because of System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to enum
I'm using .NET 9, and I'm not sure if something has changed or what the issue is, but none of the solutions for similar errors work for me.
I have the first endpoint http://localhost:5278/people/index which returns JSON with Gender enum values in text format:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyHttpClient _myHttpClient;

    public PeopleController(MyHttpClient myHttpClient)
    {
        _myHttpClient = myHttpClient;
    }

    [HttpGet("index")]
    public ActionResult<List<PersonWithGender>> Get()
    {
        var items = new List<PersonWithGender>
        {
            new PersonWithGender {
                Id = 1,
                Gender = Gender.Male
            },
            new PersonWithGender {
                Id = 2,
                Gender = Gender.Female
            }
        };

        return Ok(items);
    }

    [HttpGet("test")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<PersonWithGender>>> Test()
    {
        var items = await _myHttpClient.GetPeopleAsync();
        return items;
    }
}

This is my PersonWithGender class with the enum (I want these classes to remain clean, so they cannot have any attributes like [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]):
public class PersonWithGender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender
{
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

I added the following code to Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
        });

I have an HttpClient that calls the above endpoint and converts the retrieved data into a List<PersonWithGender>:
public class MyHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = httpClient;

    public async Task<List<PersonWithGender>> GetPeopleAsync()
    {
        var items = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<PersonWithGender>>("/people/index");
        return items;
    }
}

However, the following error occurs:

System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to WebApplication1.Models.Gender. Path: $[0].gender | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 24.'

This can be tested by calling the test endpoint: http://localhost:5278/people/test.
I tried to add:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
};

var items = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<PersonWithGender>>("/people/index", options);

But then all my data are empty, I don't know what is going on.
Here is all code: https://github.com/alekswaleks/WebApplication3/tree/master/WebApplication3

We cannot access your  http://localhost so we don't see what the JSON you are trying to parse actually looks like.

But if you way all data is "empty" (whatever that means for you, an int or an enum can't be empty), there is probably some mismatch in the property names

@derpirscher OP has attached a [mre] at github. It seems that by "empty" OP means default values.

ASP.NET Core uses Web defaults for System.Text.Json which among other things has camel case naming policy (hence your actual JSON will look something like [{"id":..., "gender":...}]), to match it use the same settings for the deserializer:
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
{
    Converters = { new JsonStringEnumConverter() }
};

var items = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<PersonWithGender>>(
   "/people/index", 
   options);

Read more:

Web defaults for JsonSerializerOptions

